# Extract the skeleton of a multipolygon

Tags: groovy, gis, h2

I'm currently working on representing the walking areas of pedestrians in the city. To do so, I retrieve an OSM file containing multiple geographic information. I have a multipolygon that represents the areas where pedestrians can be found, it is a buffer around sidewalks and other urban elements. I need to extract the skeleton of this sort of buffer in order to obtain some kind of centerline where I can sample points. I'm working on Groovy connected to the H2GIS database and I haven't really found a function that helps me do this.  Does anyone have an idea of how to proceed? I'm putting some figures so you can understand what I want.
Sorry if the info is not very clear, this is my first time posting here. Thanks in advance

I have already tried to apply an "anti-buffer" in order to simplify the geometry but this has not proven very effective.

Comment: You could review https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/2021/08/30/Skeletons.html for a starting point